# When compiling and installing opengauss on the Kirin operating system, how to deal with it without redhat lsb?

Tags: python, redhat

```
[root@node2 build]# sh build_all.sh

------------------------------openssl---------------------------------------

/opt/ogsrc/openGauss-third_party/dependency/openssl/../../build/get_PlatForm_str.sh:line:24 lsb_release: No command was found Traceback(most recent call last):

  File “build.py”,line 312,in <module>

     Operator.build_mode()

  File “build.py”,line 96,in build_mode

     Self.binary_parser()

  File “build.py”,line 87, in binary_parser

     Assert False

AssertionError
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the required dependency packages:

```
yum install -y libaio-devel flex bison ncurses-devel glibc-devel patch redhat-lsb readline-devel
```